# JOIN/Where CONCEPTS

Tags: sql, sql-server, oracle, t-sql, plsql

what is the difference between these two sql statements

a) `select * from T1,T2 where T1.A=T2.A ;`

b) `select * from T1,T2 where T2.A=T1.A ;`

I am getting the same output in both cases,is there any differences between both statements?

c) `select * from T1 inner join T2 on T1.A=T2.A ;`

What is the diffence between Statement C and a?in that case also getting the same output as of a and b...

Can Inner Joins also be written as sql statement a?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

They are all essentially different ways to join two tables using the same join condition.

Between 1 and 2, there is absolutely no difference as far as the database is concerned.

The last option is the standardized join syntax - this is what you should be using in order to ensure your SQL is readable - this is what people reading your SQL will expect to see when you join tables.

Answer (score 1):

SQL is like mathematics that way; equality is symmetric.  If A = B, then B = A.  There *should* be no difference.

The JOIN/ON notation is just another way to write the same thing.  The notation is different to emphasize the join visually.

The output tells you the answer better than any number of SO users will.  Why don't you believe your own eyes?

Answer (score 1):

All are the same there is no difference

These are diiferent ways

Answer (score 0):

(a) and (c) are same except the second is ANSI-92 SQL syntax and the first is the older SQL syntax which didn't incorporate the join clause. They should produce exactly the same internal query plan, although you may like to check.

You should use the ANSI-92 syntax for several of reasons

- The use of the JOIN clause separates the relationship logic from the
  filter logic (the WHERE) and is thus cleaner and easier to
  understand.
- It doesn't matter with this particular query, but there are a few
  circumstances where the older outer join syntax (using + ) is
  ambiguous and the query results are hence implementation dependent -
  or the query cannot be resolved at all. These do not occur with
  ANSI-92
- It's good practice as most developers and dba's will use ANSI-92
  nowadays and you should follow the standard. Certainly all modern
  query tools will generate ANSI-92.